# Сохранение контекста сопроцессора ARM Cortex A7

Tags: arm

Работаю с Cortex A7 на уровне "железа" - Bare Metal programming.
Реализовал поддержку прерываний.
Программы на С и Ассемблере. Компилятор GCC-Linaro gnueabihf. 
Все работает, но если использую плавающую арифметику в фоновой задаче и в обработчике прерывания, то в фоновой задаче вычисления работают неверно и в регистре FPSCR выскакивает 1 в 4 бите **IXC - Inexact cumulative exception flag**.
В обработчике прерывания перед работой с Floating point выполняю сохранение контекста, а после - восстановление. Вот эти процедуры:

```
vfpPush:vpush {d0-d15}
        vmrs  r0, fpscr
        push {r0}
        bx lr

vfpPop: pop  {r0}
        vmsr fpscr, r0  
        vpop {d0-d15} 
        bx lr
```

Но это не помогает! Стоит только выполнить в прерывании умножение, деление, или любую другую операцию с данными типа double, как в фоновой задаче происходит сбой (если она тоже в момент прерывания работает с double)!
Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось все просто! Опции компилятора были заданы NEON-VFPv4.
При этом компилятор использует расширенный набор регистров D0 - D31.
При этом сам компилятор неправильно трактует команду PUSH {d15-d31}.
Пришлось воспользоваться командой

```
ldc p11, cr0, [r0],#32*4
```

Теперь все заработало!